# PUGXMultiUserBundle: route "fos_user_registration_register" does not exist

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, pugxmultiuserbundle

In a continuing effort to incorporate the multi-user bundle in a project I get

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route
>   "fos_user_registration_register" as such route does not exist.") in
>   FOSUserBundle:Registration:register_content.html.twig at line 3.

I've been through the documentation several times and have not yet seen where in the following configuration I've made an error.  The above error occurs when, in dev, I go to /register/staff.  Can't figure out how we get to the original fos registration.

#### Edit: stack trace appended below, showing transition to FOSUserBundle

#### config.yml

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Vol\VolBundle\Entity\Person
#    registration:
#        form:
#            type: vol_user_registration
    service:
        user_manager: pugx_user_manager

pugx_multi_user:
  users:
    staff:
        entity: 
          class: Vol\VolBundle\Entity\Staff
#          factory: 
        registration:
          form: 
            type: Vol\VolBundle\Form\RegistrationStaffFormType
            name: fos_user_registration_form
            validation_groups:  [Registration, Default]
          template: VolVolBundle:Registration:staff.form.html.twig
        profile:
          form:
            type: Vol\VolBundle\Form\ProfileStaffFormType
            name: fos_user_profile_form
            validation_groups:  [Profile, Default] 
    volunteer:
        entity: 
          class: Vol\VolBundle\Entity\Volunteer
        registration:
          form: 
            type: Vol\VolBundle\Form\RegistrationVolunteerFormType
          template: VolVolBundle:Registration:volunteer.form.html.twig
        profile:
          form: 
            type: Vol\VolBundle\Form\ProfileVolunteerFormType
```

#### routing.yml:

```
fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /profile

#rem'd for PUGX multi-user bundle
#fos_user_register:
#    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
#    prefix: /register

fos_user_resetting:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
    prefix: /resetting

fos_user_change_password:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
    prefix: /profile

##add following for PUGX multi-user bundle
staff_registration:
    pattern:  /register/staff
    defaults: { _controller: VolVolBundle:RegistrationStaff:register }

volunteer_registration:
    pattern:  /register/volunteer
    defaults: { _controller: VolVolBundle:RegistrationVolunteer:register }
```

#### controller:

```
class RegistrationStaffController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @return type
     */
    public function registerAction()
    {
        return $this->container
                    ->get('pugx_multi_user.registration_manager')
                    ->register('Vol\VolBundle\Entity\Staff');
    }
}
```

#### By request, the templates staff.form.html.twig & staff_register_content.html.twig:

```
//staff.form.html.twig
{% extends 'VolVolBundle:Default:layout.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
Staff Registration Form
{% block fos_user_content %}
{% include 'VolVolBundle:Registration:staff_register_content.html.twig' %}
{% endblock fos_user_content %}
{% endblock %}

//staff_register_content.html.twig
{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}

<form action="{{ path('staff_registration') }}" {{ form_enctype(form) }} method="POST">
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="{{ 'registration.submit'|trans }}" />
    </div>
</form>
```

#### default layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<head>
{% stylesheets '@VolVolBundle/Resources/public/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}</head>
<body class="background" >
        {% block body %}

        {% endblock %}
</body>
```

#### stack trace

```
at Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigEngine->renderResponse('FOSUserBundle:Registration:register.html.twig', array('form' => object(FormView)))
    in G:\Documents\workspace\volunteer\vendor\friendsofsymfony\user-bundle\FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController.php line 78

at FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController->registerAction(object(Request))
    in G:\Documents\workspace\volunteer\vendor\pugx\multi-user-bundle\PUGX\MultiUserBundle\Controller\RegistrationManager.php line 63

at PUGX\MultiUserBundle\Controller\RegistrationManager->register('Vol\VolBundle\Entity\Staff')
    in G:\Documents\workspace\volunteer\src\Vol\VolBundle\Controller\RegistrationStaffController.php line 25

at Vol\VolBundle\Controller\RegistrationStaffController->registerAction()
    in  line 

at call_user_func_array(array(object(RegistrationStaffController), 'registerAction'), array())
    in G:\Documents\workspace\volunteer\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 2911

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), '1')
    in G:\Documents\workspace\volunteer\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 2883

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
    in G:\Documents\workspace\volunteer\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 3022

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
    in G:\Documents\workspace\volunteer\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 2303

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
    in G:\Documents\workspace\volunteer\web\app_dev.php line 28
```

Comment: Can you add the contents of `VolVolBundle:Registration:staff.form.html.twig`

Comment: @IanBelcher: Templates added above.

Comment: Cheers, if your `staff.form.html.twig` only has the `fos_user_content` block in it, does it work? Your extending the layout template, which by default within the FOS bundle doesn't have a body block. Have you changed the layout template at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A misunderstanding of the bundle's instructions.  A revised routing.yml, where fos_user_register is NOT commented out!

#### routing.yml

```
fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /profile

fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /register

fos_user_resetting:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
    prefix: /resetting

fos_user_change_password:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
    prefix: /profile

##add following for PUGX multi-user bundle
staff_registration:
    pattern:  /register/staff
    defaults: { _controller: VolVolBundle:RegistrationStaff:register }

volunteer_registration:
    pattern:  /register/volunteer
    defaults: { _controller: VolVolBundle:RegistrationVolunteer:register }
```

Answer (score 1):

Does 'VolVolBundle:Default:layout.html.twig' contain a registration link?

`fos_user_registration_register`route is being called somewhere in one of your templates.

Comment: A global search of the ..\src directory shows no occurrence of `fos_user_registration_register`.

Comment: I also searched `app\config` and `app\Resources` and found no instance of `fos_user_registration_register`. It only appears in FOSUserBundle - once in `registration.xml`, twice in `register_content.html.twig`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the above, I'd guess that your `VolVolBundle:Default:layout.html.twig` doesn't have a `{% block body %}` block in it?

If `VolVolBundle:Default:layout.html.twig` is a copy of the `FOSUserBunde::layout.html.twig` template, it wouldn't, which means your `{% block fos_user_content %}` is most likely not overwriting the layout template and (somehow) the FOSUserBundle defaults are being used.

Are you able to post your `VolVolBundle:Default:layout.html.twig` template as well?

Comment: Before adding the multi-user bundle, FOSUserBundle was configured to use `VolVolBundle:Default:layout.html.twig`. I've added it anyway.

Comment: That all looks good as far as I can tell. The next step I'd take is to check your parameters in `config.yml` are being read correctly at `PUGX\MultiUserBundle\Model\UserDiscriminator:205`. It could be that `PUGX\MultiUserBundle\Controller\RegistrationManager:68` isn't finding the template, and using `FOSUserBundle:Registration:register.html.twig` instead, which of course is introducing the `fos_user_registration_register` route.

Comment: I just learned that I must have misunderstood the PGUX instruction "You have to disable the default route registration coming from FOSUser..."  Based on that comment I commented out the `fos_user_register` block in `routing.yml`.  Doing my best infinite monkey approximation, I uncommented that block (see above) and VOILA! The registration forms appear.  So now I wonder what is meant by that instruction.  Have I done the second half of the instruction "...or you have to manage it for prevent incorrect registration."?

Comment: I haven't actually used multi-user before, but that's how I understood that instruction as well. The thing is, you're still using the FOS template, not the `VolVolBundle:Registration:staff.form.html.twig` as you've stipulated in your config...

Comment: Amazingly, the proper registration forms are used.  I had added text to each form (e.g., "Staff Registration Form" to the staff form) and the correct individual forms were rendered.  As a former boss called it, "It's FM", where F is the gerund form of a known Anglo-Saxon verb, M = Magic.